# How to handle multi-project builds/repos in purescript?

Tags: build, package, purescript, multi-project

We have a Purescript project that has grown organically, and it would be natural to split it up into two "binaries" and two libraries.

Since the packages are still closely related, it would be convenient to maintain them in the same git repository. Is anyone doing this?

Most purescript repos I've seen are very fine-grained, and others just put everything in one bower package.

(FWIW, part of the reason for wanting to split them is to be able to avoid pulling unnecessary transitive dependencies into downstream projects.)

Comment: You can split them and reference from local file system with Spago, I believe, but you still can't distribute "compiled binary" (i.e. compiled JavaScript), which is what you're implying here if I understand correctly. All library code comes as PureScript source and gets compiled all together, transitive dependencies and all.

Comment: I'm fine with distributing source only, but I'd rather keep the 4 packages in one repo rather than multiple, so that we can atomically commit changes across packages. I'll need to look into Spago more... Can it reference directories in remote git repos too?